# Render conflicts with my view in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm starting in Ruby on Rails and I searched for in Stack Overflow and Google and I couldn't find the solution for my problem. Actually what is happening is that I have my default view `application.html.erb` and I limited the access to some partials verifying

What I'm trying to do is put the `validates` method in the model `company.rb` and when the user mistakes, my `companies_controller.rb` to render the actual action for the user fixes.

But when I do that, my validations in the `application.html.erb` doesn't recognises the rendered action as part of the `companies_controller.rb`

`application.html.erb`

```
<body>
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <%= render 'shared/navbar' unless (controller.controller_name == "messages" && controller.action_name == "new") || (controller.controller_name == "links" && controller.action_name == "edit") || (controller.controller_name == "messages" && controller.action_name == "edit")  %>
    <%= render 'shared/sidebar' unless current_page?(root_path) || current_page?(edit_user_registration_path) || (controller.controller_name == "companies" && controller.action_name == "index") || (controller.controller_name == "companies" && controller.action_name == "new") || current_page?(new_company_path) || (controller.controller_name == "links" && controller.action_name == "edit") || (controller.controller_name == "messages" && controller.action_name == "new") || (controller.controller_name == "messages" && controller.action_name == "edit") %>
    <% end %>
    <%= yield %>
</body>
```

`create` method from `companies_controller.rb`

```
def create
    @company = current_user.companies.new(company_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @company.save
        current_user.companies << @company
        format.html { redirect_to @company, notice: 'Company was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @company }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @company.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

`_form.html.erb`

```
<%= form_with(model: company, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if company.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(company.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this company from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% company.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_field :name, id: :company_name, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :phone %>
    <%= form.text_field :phone, id: :company_phone, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :category %>
    <%= form.text_field :category, id: :company_category, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :active %>
    <%= form.check_box :active %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <%= link_to 'Back', companies_path, class: "btn btn-default" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

`company.rb`

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
    validates :name, uniqueness: true, presence: true

    has_many :folders, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :analytics, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :leads, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :messages, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :links, :dependent => :destroy

    has_many :user_companies, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :users, :through => :user_companies
end
```

And the error is `ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Companies#create`

Can someone help with that? Sorry for my english.

Thank you!

**Update December, 08.**

My `routes.rb`

```
scope '/dashboard' do
    resources :companies do
      resources :users
      resources :user_companies
      resources :folder_links
      resources :folders
      resources :analytics
      resources :leads
      resources :links
      resources :messages

      get 'user_companies/new/search', to: "user_companies#search"
    end
  end
```

Comment: `ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Companies#create` is probably from `redirect_to @company`... Can you add the relevant routes from your routes.rb file to the question?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error adding another validation. What was happening is that I was missing one more validation on `application.html.erb`:

```
<%= render 'shared/navbar' unless (controller.controller_name == "messages" && controller.action_name == "new") || (controller.controller_name == "links" && controller.action_name == "edit") || (controller.controller_name == "messages" && controller.action_name == "edit")  %>
<%= render 'shared/sidebar' unless current_page?(root_path) || current_page?(edit_user_registration_path) || (controller.controller_name == "companies" && controller.action_name == "index") || (controller.controller_name == "companies" && controller.action_name == "new") || current_page?(new_company_path) || (controller.controller_name == "links" && controller.action_name == "edit") || (controller.controller_name == "messages" && controller.action_name == "new") || (controller.controller_name == "messages" && controller.action_name == "edit") %>
```

I just added the condition to when the current action is `create`:

```
<%= render 'shared/navbar' unless (controller.controller_name == "messages" && controller.action_name == "new") || (controller.controller_name == "links" && controller.action_name == "edit") || (controller.controller_name == "messages" && controller.action_name == "edit")  %>
<%= render 'shared/sidebar' unless current_page?(root_path) || current_page?(edit_user_registration_path) || (controller.controller_name == "companies" && controller.action_name == "index") || (controller.controller_name == "companies" && controller.action_name == "create") || (controller.controller_name == "companies" && controller.action_name == "new") || current_page?(new_company_path) || (controller.controller_name == "links" && controller.action_name == "edit") || (controller.controller_name == "messages" && controller.action_name == "new") || (controller.controller_name == "messages" && controller.action_name == "edit") %>
```

Sorry for waste your time.

Thank you for trying to help, guys!

Answer (score 0):

@Lucas although it solved your problem, I wouldn't recommend the long unless condition you have put. I don't know why you have to check for controller action. Best way to do this is to call the render from the controller action. You can optimize this code.

Comment: It's a design thing. For example, I don't want that the sidebar and the navbar (both between the unless condition) appears on my login page. And in another situation, I don't want that this both items appears in my new message page. How do I optimize this code calling render from the controller action? Thank you for your help!